# Hide other previous div/dropdown React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am wanting to hide other sibling divs (dropdowns in my case) when I click the `statusPillDropdown`

so far I click I am setting the status to true and opening the div,

```
{DropDown ${toggleStatusDropdown ? "open": ""}}
```

Do I just need to set the state to false for previously opened ones? Not sure how to do this.

thank you

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./StatusPillDropdown.scss";

function StatusPillDropdown({
  cellData,
  rowItemId,
  onStatusPillDropdownChange
}) {
const [toggleStatusDropdown, setToggleStatusDropdown] = useState();

const toggleDropdown = (action, rowItemId, e) => {
  if (action === "pillClick") {
    setToggleStatusDropdown(true);
  } else {
    onStatusPillDropdownChange(rowItemId, e.target.getAttribute("value"));
    setToggleStatusDropdown(false);
  }
};

const renderstatusPillDropdown = (cellData, rowItemId) => (
<React.Fragment>
  <span
    className="statusPillDropdown"
    onClick={() => toggleDropdown("pillClick", rowItemId)}
  >
    <span className={`status-pill ${cellData.type}`}>{cellData.text}</span>
  </span>
  <div className="status">
    <div className="dropdown-container">
      <div className={`DropDown ${toggleStatusDropdown ? "open" : ""}`}>
        <ul>
          <li
            value="Information only"
            onClick={e => toggleDropdown("liClick", rowItemId, e)}
          >
            <span></span>Information only
          </li>
          <li
            value="Unresolved"
            onClick={e => toggleDropdown("liClick", rowItemId, e)}
          >
            <span className="unresolved"></span>Unresolved
          </li>
          <li
            value="Partially Resolved"
            onClick={e => toggleDropdown("liClick", rowItemId, e)}
          >
            <span className="partyResolved"></span>Partially Resolved
          </li>
          <li
            value="Fully Resolved"
            onClick={e => toggleDropdown("liClick", rowItemId, e)}
          >
            <span className="resolved"></span>Fully Resolved
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</React.Fragment>
);

return (
  <React.Fragment>
    {renderstatusPillDropdown(cellData, rowItemId)}
  </React.Fragment>
);
}

export default StatusPillDropdown;
```